# Convert Ogg Vorbis to MP3 with Metadata

Tags: windows, conversion, mp3, id3, ogg

I've got a few hundred megs of Ogg Vorbis files I've collected over the years that I want to convert to MP3 so I can put them on my iPhone (among other things.)

Converting from one file format to the other isn't all that hard (see, for example, [this other SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/15327/how-to-convert-ogg-to-mp3).)

But - the ogg files I've got have fully loaded metadata headers that I really want to be carried into the ID3 tags of the resulting MP3 file.  So far, I havn't been able to find a program that will batch convert OGG to MP3 AND port over all metadata.

(I'd also like something Free/Open Source and windows based, if possible.)

Comment: It might help if you list the programs you've tried - so you don't get them suggested.

Comment: In case this wasn't nerdy enough already, and if someone was curious, I'm looking to convert the Sierra soundtrack OGG files from here: http://www.queststudios.com/.  Space Quest FTW.

Comment: @ChrisF: Fair enough.  Mostly, I've been using Goldwave and Adobe Audition, which both can get the job done, but not real conveniently.  (Of course, if it turns out I just missed a checkbox in goldwave somewhere, that would be a best-case scenario.)

Comment: Please see here for my simple script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/442997/how-can-i-convert-audio-from-ogg-to-mp3/1064524#1064524

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com)?

I've just converted an mp3 to ogg (as I knew I had mp3's with meta data) and the meta data (Title, Artist, Genre, Album, Year, Track no.) got copied. I've also converted it back to mp3 and the meta data is preserved that way too.

It will also do batch conversions. Just add your ogg files to the library, select them all and then Tools > Convert Audio Format works on all the selected items. I've recently discovered that you don't have to add the tracks to your library. Media Monkey's built in browser can look at files directly.

It comes with a time limited mp3 encoder (30 days if I remember), but you can replace it with an unlimited one by simply updating the dll.

Comment: Wow, never even heard of it, but that looks awesome.  I think that's going to be my first try once I get home.

Comment: Well I've been very pleased with it all round. Ripping, tagging and organising and playback.

Comment: Wow, Media Monkey is spectacular.  How did I never hear about it before now?  Thanks, ChrisF.